# Issue with Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'getParentId' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: magento

PHP 7.2.34
Getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'getParentId' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /chroot/home/s33434/newsite.com/app/code/Zsingle/Ztheme/Helper/context.php on line 20

```
 namespace Zsingle\Ztheme\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $configurable;
    protected $grouped;
    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
        Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $grouped
    )
    {
    $this->configurable = $configurable;
    $this->grouped = $grouped;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public getParentId($childId){
    /* for simple product of configurable product */
        product = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
        if(isset($product[0])){
            return $product[0];
       }

    /* for simple product of Group product */
       $parentIds = $this->grouped->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
        /* or for Group/Bundle Product */
           $product->getTypeInstance()->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the PHP version you're using you need to specify 'function'.

```
public getParentId($childId){
```

should become

```
public function getParentId($childId){
```